# Like/Unlike Without Ajax or jQuery on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm trying to implement a simple like/unlike function. All the examples I have seen here seem to apply to ajax or jquery. I.m still a beginner and I don't fully understand either yet, I just want a simple solution.

My idea is, I have books and I have users. Users can like books. So I have created a many-to-many association through a Like model. The Like model has a corresponding database with book_id and user_id columns. Thus:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, through: :likes

class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :likes
  has_many :books, through: :likes

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

unfortunately, this is as far as my understanding goes. I do not know how to utilize this relationship to create likes and associate them with the appropriate book and user.

My idea is to present the user a 'like' button if he has not liked the book, or unlike if he hasn't. So basically, I want to have something this simple:

```
<%  if user likes? %>

<div class="unlike_button"><%= link_to "Unlike", '#' %></div>

<% else %>

<div class="like_button"><%= link_to "Like", '#' %></div>

<% end %>
```

I used the # stub because I have no idea what route it should use. But whatever the solution is, I would like it to redirect to the same page with a flash notice saying "liked" or "Unlike". 
I already have div background images for the like_button and unlike_button classes, which is why I implement them as image links above.

Any sort of guidance or help, would be deeply appreciated. Thanks

*UPDATE*

I'm following Bennick's guidance here below but I', still stuck in the rails console. I figure there's no point moving forward if I'm getting errors in the console.

As suggested, I tried this in the console:

As I already have users I did `user = User.find(1)`and `book = Book.find(1)`

But on the next line  `like = Like.create(:user => user, :book => book)`the returned a mass assign error. `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: book, user`
I figured maybe this would help `attr_accessible :book_id, :user_id` in the like model but I still get errors. Am I missing something?

*SOLVED*

I finally got it to work! Using `like = Like.create(:user => user.id, :book => book.id)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay there are a number of items here. I'm going to walk you up the *stack* (*model* -> *associations* -> *controller* -> *view* -> *router*). Typically when you design a web application you start with the database layer and work your way up. So we will do that here.

**Model**

This is where you decide what database objects you need and create database tables to represent them. If you have not already, read the Rails Guide to migrations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

In your case this setup would be appropriate:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title

  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, through: :likes
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :likes
  has_many :books, through: :likes
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book, :user

  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Notice that we need include `attr_accessible` so we don't get any mass-assignment errors. Please not that in Rails 4 this security feature has moved into the controller. For more on this see these or search the inter webs:
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/rails-4-strong-paremeters
http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/

**Associations**

You should read the Rails guide on associations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

This will give you a good idea on how database objects (Active Record objects) interact with one another. In your question you have already set these up. Once an association is made Rails provides a number of methods used to access them. Here is an example rails console session: `rails c`

```
# Create a user
user = User.create(:name => "Ryan") # I'm assuming User just requires a name for simplicity
  => #<User id: 1, name: "Ryan">
# Create two a books
book = Book.create(:title => "Game of Thrones")
  => #<Book id: 1, title: "Game of Thrones">
book2 = Book.create(:title => "The Well-Grounded Rubyist")
  => #<Book id: 2, title: "The Well-Grounded Rubyist">
# Create a two likes from the books and the user record
like = Like.create(:user => user, :book => book)
  => #<Like id: 1, user_id: 1, book_id: 1>
like2 = Like.create(:user => user, :book => book2)
  => #<Like id: 2, user_id: 1, book_id: 2>
# Notice how the keys glue the associations

# Query a user's likes
user.likes.count
  => 2
user.likes
  => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Like id: 1, user_id: 1, book_id: 1>, #<Like id: 2, user_id: 1, book_id: 2>]
# Query a user's books
user.books
  => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Book id: 1, title: "Game of Thrones">, #<Book id: 1, title: "The Well-Grounded Rubyist">]
```

When in doubt play with the rails console. You will learn a ton from it.

**Controller**

In order for the end user to interact with your database objects a controller is necessary to facilitate the exchange. Again, read the associated Rails Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html
If you have not guessed by now I highly recommend reading most of these.

In your cause we are creating like objects so lets make a likes controller:

`rails g controller likes index`

This will create the controller with an index action and view file.

```
# app/controllers/likes_controller.rb
class LikesController < ApplicationController

  # This action will show our likes for a user.
  # Lets assume you have an authentication system (ex Devise) that logs a user in and provides a `current_user` object
  # GET /likes
  def index
    # Assign the logged in user to @user
    @user = current_user
    # Grab all of the books and put them into an array in @books
    @books = Book.all
  end

  # This is our key action. We will use this action to create a Like
  # POST /likes
  def create
    # Grab our book from the DB. Note that this syntax is for Rails 3.2 and below. Rails 4 uses something called Strong Parameters, but that is for another time. 
    book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    # Create a like
    Like.create(:book => book, :user => current_user)
    # redirect back to the Like index page and assign a flash
    redirect_to likes_path, :notice => "You just liked the book #{book.title}" 
  end

  # here is where we will destroy a Like
  # DELETE /likes/:id
  def destroy
    # Get the like form the DB
    like = Like.find(params[:id])
    # destroy it
    like.destroy
    redirect_to likes_path, :notice => "You destroyed a like"
  end
end
```

**Router**

The router is what connects external http requests to your controller actions. In your case all you will need is this:

```
# config/routers.rb
 MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :likes

 end
```

This is a Rails shortcut that sets up 7 standard routes with associated helpers:

```
    likes GET    /likes(.:format)          likes#index
          POST   /likes(.:format)          likes#create
 new_like GET    /likes/new(.:format)      likes#new
edit_like GET    /likes/:id/edit(.:format) likes#edit
     like GET    /likes/:id(.:format)      likes#show
          PUT    /likes/:id(.:format)      likes#update
          DELETE /likes/:id(.:format)      likes#destroy
```

Do yourself a favor and read this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
It will explain what these routes are and how they work. Rails follows REST as does most of the modern web development world.

**View**

In your view you will need a form for users to interact with. This form will send data to the application, specifically to your LikesController actions.

```
# app/views/likes/index.html.erb

# show your flash messages
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert <%= "alert-#{name}" %>">
    <%= msg %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h1>Books you may or may not like</h1>
# For each book
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <% unless @user.books.include?(book) %> # Prob want to move this into a User instance method
    # Create a like form if the user does not have a like for this book
    <%= form_tag likes_path do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'book_id', book.id %>
      # Clicking this sends a request: POST /likes with params of: book_id=123
      <%= submit_tag "Like this book", :class => "like_button" %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    # Find the like. I'll admit there is probably a better way to do this but it's getting past my bed time. 
    <% like = book.likes.where(:user_id => @user.id).first %>
    # Destroy the like associated with this book and user
    <div class="unlike_button">
      # Clicking this sends a request to: DELETE /likes/123
      <%= link_to "destroy like", likes_path(like.id), :method => :delete %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Conclusion**

I hope this gives you some guidance.

In the future try and keep your questions more specific as this question covered a big area. I'm just starting to actively give back so I might have over done it. I received a ton of free guidance and help when first starting out. It's about time I return the favor.

Take your time and when you get an error, just post it into Google. You will probably end up with a Stack Overflow question.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Bennick. Thanks a lot for this comprehensive response. I have already voted you up. I would have voted as the right answer if I wasn't still stuck at rails console. I just edited the question to reflect where I'm stuck. Please review

Comment: I finally got it to work! Using `like = Like.create(:user => user.id, :book => book.id)`. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @muyiwamat I'm more than happy to help. I also updated my answer under the Model section. FYI using `attr_accessible :book_id, :user_id` will allow you to assign by model ids. Using `attr_accessible :book, :user` will allow you to assign by the full model objects.

Comment: Hi @bennick, I'm a little confused. Are you saying I should go back to using `like = Like.create(:user => user, :book => book)` and make attr_accessible `attr_accessible :book, :user`? Also, I'm trying to implement the like buttons on the books index page but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I'm saying you can do either. If the way you have it works than stick with that.

Comment: What issues are you having with the like buttons? Remember to be specific in your questions. Also, didn't test this code so it is possible there would be a mistake somewhere.

Comment: It's fine now. I just change the routes of the books page to likes and I now show books on the like index page. Thanks very much for your help. I have voted you up :)

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with your app building.