# Device/CanCan - How to split a controller's actions by user role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I have an action in my app called "like" that is an action inside the book controller, ie, my Devise users can "like" a book which adds it to their profile.

In CanCan, I want users with role=="author" to be able to create, update, delete their own books, which works fine. The problem is that I want any user to be able to "like" any book. When I add that ability, I am letting users "manage" all books - how do I restrict it so all users can Like/Unlike books, but author users can manage books that they own?

Any tips are appreciated!

ability.rb

```
def initialize(user)
    # Guest User 
    can :read, :all
    unless user 
      can :read, :all
    else
      # All registered users
      can :read, :all  
      can :manage, Like
      can :manage, Book 
      # Authors 
      if user.role == 'author'
        can :read, :all
        can :create, Recommendation
        can :manage, Recommendation do |r|
            user && r.user == user
        end
        can :create, Book
        can :manage, Book do |b|
            user && b.user == user
            end 
      # Admins
      elsif user.role == 'admin'
        can :manage, :all
      end
    end 
  end
```

likes controller

```
before_action :set_project
load_and_authorize_resource

def create
    if Like.create(liked: @book, user: current_user)
      redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book has been favorited'
    else
      redirect_to @book, alert: 'Something went wrong'
    end
  end
  def destroy
    Like.where(liked_id: @book.id, user_id: current_user.id).first.destroy
    redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book is no longer in favorites'
  end

  private

  def set_project
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id] || params[:id])
  end
  def like_params
      params.require(:like).permit(:user_id, :book_id)
  end
end
```

book show

```
<% unless current_user.liked_books.exists?(id: @book.id) %>
<%= link_to 'Add to likes', like_path, method: :post %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to 'Remove from likes', like_path(@book), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a violation of CRUD principle.
First of all remove `like` action from book_controller.rb.
It's a like, not a book. This action should be `create` in like_controller.rb.
The relation should be like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Now, to add like to book, just create it, linked with user and book.**

```
Like.new(book_id: params[:book_id], user_id: params[:user_id])
```

List likes:

```
Book.find(id).likes # list all likes for book
User.find(id).likes # list all likes made by user
```

Permissions should be like this:

```
#Registered user
can :create, Like
can :destroy, Like.where(user_id: user.id)
```

Comment: If you need more information about this realization, just ask me. I will expand my answer.

Comment: thanks! I am finally getting around to doing this. I updated my Likes Controller above and my Book Show (where users should be able to add/remove likes). I don't seem to be doing it right. Do I need Like/Dislike actions rather than Create/Destory?

Comment: I'm finding this to be helpful as well! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451962/like-unlike-without-ajax-or-jquery-on-rails